# How is += done with kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Should be a simple thing to do but I can't get it to work.

`counter += 1` doesn't work.
`counter.inc()` doesn't increase `counter`, it remains the same. `.plusAssign` is not recognised. `.plus()` doesn't work, `counter` doesn't increase. Am I missing something?

***UPDATE*** 
The problem is probably in some other area as the normal `+=` does work in a clean project. I'm using a counter in a swipe function like this:

```
override fun onSwipingLeft(event: MotionEvent?) {
            Log.d("TAG", "LEFT")

            counter!! += 1

            Log.d("TAG", "LEFT" + counterV)

            Picasso.with(context).load(recipeArray!![counterV].recipeImage).into(recipe_image_container_id)

        }
```

Gives an error by `counter` saying that variable is expected whatever that means.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `var`, not `val`? Cause `val`s are final and should not be modified.

Comment: Depends on what your code is. -_-

Comment: You may want to show your code, otherwise there isn't really a way anyone can know for sure.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? Where did you test it?

Comment: where did you declare `counter`?

Answer (score 4):

> How is += done with kotlin?

With `+=`:

```
var foo = 1

foo += 5

println(foo)
```

The output is `6`:

[image: Kotlin REPL Output]

You can [try running it yourself](https://repl.it/repls/GlaringSociableArchitects).

Answer (score 0):

Are you reassigning the variable?

```
counter = counter.inc()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it says `variable expected`, even though I added `var counterX = counter` or is it referring to something else?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using `val` modifier, so `counter` is `final`, and it's value could not be modified after initial assignment. Try to change it to `var counter` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I added `var counterX = counter` but that didn't solve the problem. Log still show no increase.